# Cannot receive PayPal IPN - PayPal always gets a 403 error

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to receive IPN message inside a wordpress application (to know when a payment occured). Wordpress runs on linux/apache (PHP as FastCGI).

After payment however I'm not receiving the IPNs on the server. It looks like PayPal is unable to send them to my server as it receives a 403 status code ("No Permissions"). The SSL access log shows the following:

```
173.0.81.1 - - [04/Sep/2015:08:44:40 +0200] "POST /index.php?sell_media-listener=IPN HTTP/1.0" 403 9402 "-" "PayPal IPN ( https://www.paypal.com/ipn )"
173.0.81.33 - - [04/Sep/2015:08:44:59 +0200] "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 9533 "-" "-"
```

First line above shows an original call by PayPal that was done after a transaction. Seconds line is from a test call by the IPN simulator of PayPal, this time not to the script/function that processes IPN but directly to the normal index.php which should be accessible for everyone. Both times a 403 was returned.

Does anybody know why PayPal receives this 403 and not a 200 status code? So far I heard that it could be that my hoster (and many other web hosting companies) blocks requests without a user agent string and PayPal (according to them) is doing this.

The IPN listener on my side does, as far that I know, now submit also a user agent string in the curl request to PayPal, but still no change is visible.

I also added the following lines to the beginning of my .htaccess file inside the root directory of my wordpress folder:

```
Allow from .paypal.com
Allow from api.paypal.com
Allow from api-3t.paypal.com
Allow from api-aa.paypal.com
Allow from api-aa-3t.paypal.com
Allow from api-s.paypal.com
Allow from api-m.paypal.com
Allow from svcs.paypal.com
Allow from notify.paypal.com
Allow from reports.paypal.com
Allow from ipnpb.paypal.com
Allow from www.paypal.com
Allow from mobile.paypal.com
Allow from m.paypal.com
Allow from www.paypalobjects.com
Allow from pointofsale.paypal.com
```

But this also changed nothing. My hoster was not very helpful, he just said "make sure to send a user agent string...".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IPN begins with _an inbound post *from PayPal to you*, not a post from you to them (although after receiving PayPal's post you then post to them to verify). It is this inbound post that your hosting provider is reporting that they block.

You cannot change how PayPal makes this post; it is PayPal's code, not yours.

And your own web server configuration is likely not what is blocking the post; it may be an upstream system administered by the hosting provider (or at least, that is what you are reporting -- have you verified this with the actual hosting provider, versus having "heard" that sometimes happens?)

So if your hosting company's explanation is blocking PayPal's post, your only options are:

1) talk to your hosting company and convince them to change their policy or make an exception to not block PayPal IPN posts, or

2) host your IPN script somewhere else (with a hosting provider that will not block PayPal's IPNs)